# How to compare to BigInts in Java to determine which one is the larger BigInt

Tags: java, boolean, bigint

I'm trying to compare two BigInts that were manually created and did not use the built-in BigInt class.  Right now I'm getting hung up trying to be able to determine how to find the bigger number of the 2. For example if I want to find which number is bigger between 123 and 134, and I pass in both BigInts I want to return a false if 123 is the first number passed or True if the second number is passed.  Please see the code below:

```
private boolean thisBigIntGreaterThanOrEqualToOther(BigInt b1, BigInt b2){
      boolean value = true;
      if(b1.bigInt.size() >= b2.bigInt.size()){
          for(int i = 0; i < b2.bigInt.size(); i++){
              if(b1.bigInt.get(i) >= b2.bigInt.get(i)){
                  value = true;
              }
              else{
                 value = false;
              }
          }
      }
      else{
          value = false;
      }
      return value;
  }
```

As you can see in my code I thought about trying to compare each digit, but I run into an issue when I get to 1's for each number, it sets the value to true.

BigInt Class Below:

```
    public class BigInt {

       //Instance variables for the class, a boolean for the sign and an ArrayList to store the input String

       private boolean pos = true;
       private ArrayList<Integer> bigInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       //No argument constructor, creates a big integer of value zero

       public BigInt () {
           this.pos = true;



       }

     //Constructor for big integers input as int

       public BigInt (int newBigInt) {
          String inputInt = Integer.toString(newBigInt);
           inputInt = handleSign(inputInt);
           inputInt = checkNumber(inputInt);
           for(int i = inputInt.length() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
               bigInt.add(Integer.parseInt(inputInt.substring(i, i+1)));
           }
       }

       //Constructor for big integers input as strings

       public BigInt (String newBigInt) {

           newBigInt = handleSign(newBigInt);
           newBigInt = checkNumber(newBigInt);
           for(int i = newBigInt.length() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
               bigInt.add(Integer.parseInt(newBigInt.substring(i, i+1)));
           }
       }
private String handleSign(String num) {

       if(num.charAt(0) == '+' || num.charAt(0) == '-') {
           if(num.length() == 1) {
               throw new ErrorMessage("Invalid value: sign only, no integer.");
           }

           if(num.charAt(0) == '-') {
               this.pos = false;
           }

           else {
               this.pos = true;
           }
           num = num.substring(1);
       }

       return num;
   }
   // Private method to remove leading zeros from add/subtract methods

   private BigInt removeZeros(BigInt result){

       for(int i = 0; i < result.bigInt.size(); i++){
           if(result.bigInt.get(i) == 0){
               result.bigInt.remove(i);
           }
       }
       return result;
   }

   //Private method to check the number; remove leading zeros and check for leading spaces (throw error message)

   private String checkNumber(String num) {

       if(num.charAt(0) == ' ') {
           throw new ErrorMessage("Invalid value: leading blank space.");
       }
       if(num.charAt(0) == '0'){
           while(num.length() > 1 && num.charAt(0) == '0') {
               num = num.substring(1);
           }
       }
       return num;
   }

   //toString method

public String toString() {

       String answer = "";
       for(int i = bigInt.size() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
           answer = answer + bigInt.get(i);
       }
       if(this.pos == false){
           return "-" + answer;
       }
    return answer;
```

Comment: Please post your definition of the `BigInt` class.

Comment: *but I run into an issue when I get to 1's for each number, it sets the value to true.* Is not `1 >= 1`? Your loop body is *equivalent* to `value = b1.bigInt.get(i) >= b2.bigInt.get(i);` Instead of `value = false;` in your loop body, I think you want to short-circuit with `return false;` Once you have determined that `b1` is less than `b2` you're done. You could also add a `break;`

Comment: I went ahead and added the BigInt class above.  Sorry, also i'm really just starting to learn alot of this, so this is all kind of new to me.  Ideally i'm trying to be able to subtract to BigInts, so that why I would like to be able to determine which one is the actual larger number.

Answer (score 3):

The method to compare two `BigInt`s is broken in several ways:

**1. You iterate in the wrong direction:**

`for(int i = 0; i < b2.bigInt.size(); i++)`

You start from the least significant digit which means `20` would be considered smaller than `11`. Change it to

`for(int i = b2.bigInt.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)`

**2. You override the result of the comparison**

If your code reaches the point where it sets `value = false;` it does not return or exit the loop. That means that in the next iteration the value gets overriden. That means suddenly `13` and `23` are considered equal.

```
BigInt c = new BigInt("13");
BigInt d = new BigInt("23");
System.out.println(BigInt.thisBigIntGreaterThanOrEqualToOther(c, d));
System.out.println(BigInt.thisBigIntGreaterThanOrEqualToOther(d, c));
```

The output is

```
true
true
```

Change `value = false;` to `return false;`

**3. You do not check whether `b1.bigInt.size() > b2.bigInt.size()`**

This results in your method returning that `131` is smaller than `23`.

Change your code in the following way:

```
if(b1.bigInt.size() > b2.bigInt.size()){
  return true;
} else if(b1.bigInt.size() < b2.bigInt.size()){
  return false;
} else {
  // the other comparison code
}
```

**Some final remarks:**

It is good design to implement the [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) as it allows you to use many library methods with your class.

EDIT: code now does not use library functions anymore

```
public class BigInt implements Comparable<BigInt> {

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BigInt other) {
        int c = this.bigInt.size() - other.bigInt.size();
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        } else {
            for (int i = this.bigInt.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                c = this.bigInt.get(i) - other.bigInt.get(i);
                if (c != 0) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am trying to subtract 11 from 20, in order to determine which number is bigger, shouldn't I start from the least significant digit? Because if I go the otherway, when it compares the first digits yes 2 is larger than 1, but then when it gets to the last digit it may set 1 as larger to zero.  The problem is I can't use the built in Compare methods, kind of need to make my own comparison.  I figured I can remove all digits that are equal and then compare what's left.  Just don't know how to go from there.

Comment: You only have to compare digits (starting from the most significant one) until you find 2 that are not equal. 
Well you can just use `if(b1bigInt.get(i) < b2.bigInt.get(i))` instead of the built-in functions, I just use them for convenience ^^

Comment: Sorry I meant `b1.bigInt.get(i) - b2.bigInt.get(i)`. I updated the code too.